# Docker container id guard bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I build a bash script to verify if certain container exists or not. If there is no input, it complains. Does your mind helping me?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] 
    then echo "Docker container ID not supplied" 
elif [[ docker images | grep -q $1 ]] 
    then echo "No such container $1" 
else 
    echo $1 
fi;
```

Edit:

A common output for docker images is the sample below. In case the token matches the 12 input characters and no more, the container indeed exists.

```
REPOSITORY                   TAG            IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
sappio                       latest         091f1bf3491c   About an hour ago   556MB
postgres                     11.4           53912975086f   3 years ago         312MB
node                         7.7.2-alpine   95b4a6de40c3   5 years ago         59.2MB
```

The use cases for this shell script are:

1.

```
input: bash has_contained_id.sh
output: Docker container ID not supplied
```

2. 

```
input: bash has_contained_id.sh 1
output: "No such container 1"
```

3. 

```
input: bash has_contained_id.sh 091f1bf3491
output: "No such container 091f1bf3491"
```

4. 

```
input: bash has_contained_id.sh 091f1bf3491c
output: "091f1bf3491c"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming OP is receiving an error like:

```
./testme: line 9: conditional binary operator expected
./testme: line 9: syntax error near `images'
./testme: line 9: `elif [[ docker images | grep -q $1 ]]`
```

Then OP may want to consider the following modification:

```
# replace this:

elif [[ docker images | grep -q $1 ]]

# with this:

elif docker images | grep -q "$1"
```

---

Taking into consideration OP's additional requirements to match on an exact container name, and switching the `echo` calls for the `elif` and `else` blocks:

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Docker container ID not supplied" 
elif docker images | grep -qw "$1"; then
    echo "$1"    
else 
    echo "No such container $1" 
fi
```

Comment: I thnak you, sir! Normally a docker images line is as follow `sappio                       latest         091f1bf3491c   About an hour ago   556MB`. The grep command catches incomplete cases like "091f1bf3491". How may I access the whole token instead of partially?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto added a section to the answer to address what I *think* you're asking about; if that doesn't answer your comment/question they please update the question with more details and sample inputs (ie, sample `docker images` output and the value of `$1`)

Comment: I added the expected use cases to clarify the question

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto  I think your have your logic for the last 2 blocks backwards ... I'm assuming you want to print just the token if `grep -qw` is successful and then the `else` becomes `No such container $1`?? see updated answer

Comment: I posted my own version. You may suggest further improvements.

Answer (score 0):

With @markp-fuso I am able to achieve the shell script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]];
    then echo "Docker container ID not supplied" 
elif docker images | grep -qw "$1"; then
    len=$(expr length "$1")
    
    if [[ "$len" -eq "12" ]]; then
        echo $1
    else 
        echo "No such container $1" 
    fi;

else
    echo "No such container $1" 
fi;
```

Comment: `expr` is a bit old school and in this case not needed since the length of a variable can be obtained with `${#1}`; so, no need for `len=$(expr length "$1")` and the follow-on test can be replaced with `[[ "${#1}" -eq 12 ]]`

Comment: We can say I am timeless.